# Prove that the function $f$ pointwise limit of a function sequence $(f_n)$ is continous, where $(f_n)$ follows a certain property.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n: I \to \Bbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions such that for all $(x_n)$ a sequence that conveges, the sequence $(f_n(x_n))$ converges. ($I$ is an interval)

$(f_n)$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ (take a constant sequence).
I want to prove that $f$ is continous.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you any thoughts or progress?

Comment: Honestly the only thing I could prove is that if $x_n$ converges to $x$, then $(f_n(x_n))$ converges to $f(x)$ I'm still very far from the result

Comment: Yes Thank you. Should I delete this?

Comment: You could delete it.  I've voted to *close* as duplicate, but the duplicate target gives a much clearer statement of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

> There is a rule that if interval $I$ is closed and finite, then $f$ is continuous and monotonous, with terms $\min$ and $\sup$